# How could I play a pcm file in iOS?

Tags: ios, pcm

As the title said, how to play a pcm file on iPhone ?
Where can I get some sample code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVAudioPLayer will do it.  PCM is really just a wave without a header. I'd consider adding the header.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Speak Here Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html).

See `AQPlayer::AQBufferCallback`; that is where you would copy the LPCM data to be played back into `inCompleteAQBuffer->mAudioData`.